# PCA projection and reconstruction in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I can perform PCA in scikit by code below:
X_train has 279180 rows and 104 columns.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=30)
X_train_pca = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Now, when I want to project the eigenvectors onto feature space, I must do following:

```
""" Projection """
comp = pca.components_ #30x104
com_tr = np.transpose(pca.components_) #104x30
proj = np.dot(X_train,com_tr) #279180x104 * 104x30 = 297180x30
```

But I am hesitating with this step, because Scikit [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.inverse_transform) says:

> components_: array, [n_components, n_features]
>
> Principal axes **in feature space**, representing the directions of maximum  variance in the data.

It seems to me, that it is already projected, but when I checked the source code, it returns only the eigenvectors.

**What is the right way how to project it?**

Ultimately, I am aiming to calculate the MSE of reconstruction.

```
""" Reconstruct """
recon = np.dot(proj,comp) #297180x30 * 30x104 = 279180x104

"""  MSE Error """
print "MSE = %.6G" %(np.mean((X_train - recon)**2))
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can do

```
proj = pca.inverse_transform(X_train_pca)
```

That way you do not have to worry about how to do the multiplications.

What you obtain after `pca.fit_transform` or `pca.transform` are what is usually called the "loadings" for each sample, meaning how much of each component you need to describe it best using a linear combination of the `components_` (the principal axes in feature space).

The projection you are aiming at is back in the original signal space. This means that you need to go back into signal space using the components and the loadings.

So there are three steps to disambiguate here. Here you have, step by step, what you can do using the PCA object and how it is actually calculated:

1. `pca.fit` estimates the components (using an SVD on the centered Xtrain):

   ```
    from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
    import numpy as np
    from numpy.testing import assert_array_almost_equal

    #Should this variable be X_train instead of Xtrain?
    X_train = np.random.randn(100, 50)

    pca = PCA(n_components=30)
    pca.fit(X_train)

    U, S, VT = np.linalg.svd(X_train - X_train.mean(0))

    assert_array_almost_equal(VT[:30], pca.components_)
   ```
2. `pca.transform` calculates the loadings as you describe

   ```
    X_train_pca = pca.transform(X_train)

    X_train_pca2 = (X_train - pca.mean_).dot(pca.components_.T)

    assert_array_almost_equal(X_train_pca, X_train_pca2)
   ```
3. `pca.inverse_transform` obtains the projection onto components in signal space you are interested in

   ```
    X_projected = pca.inverse_transform(X_train_pca)
    X_projected2 = X_train_pca.dot(pca.components_) + pca.mean_

    assert_array_almost_equal(X_projected, X_projected2)
   ```

You can now evaluate the projection loss

```
loss = np.sum((X_train - X_projected) ** 2, axis=1).mean()
```

Comment: Ok, so I can call `pca.fit` to calculate the components, then the projection can be calculated by `pca.fit_transform` (that is also when I want to work further with the data - fetch them to some model since the dimensionality is reducted). And for reconstruction, I call `pca.invert_transform` to calculate MSE. Is that correct?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by projection. First, note that `pca.fit_transform(X)` gives the same result as `pca.fit(X).transform(X)` (it is an optimized shortcut). Second, a projection is generally something that goes from one space into the same space, so here it would be from signal space to signal space, with the property that applying it twice is like applying it once. Here it would be `f= lambda X: pca.inverse_transform(pca.transform(X))`. You can check that `f(f(X)) == f(X).` So I would call that the projection. `pca.transform` is obtaining the loadings. In the end it's just terminolgy

Comment: By projection I mean transforming the vectors onto feature space. It is what I did in my question (second step) and it is the same what `pca.transform(X)` does - result is matrix _Mxk_, where _M_ is number of rows and _k_ number of selected components. I will use this as input to models (and i should expect better results than using original dataset)

Comment: Then use the pipeline. `from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline` then `pipeline = make_pipeline(PCA(n_components=30), your_classifier)` and you can use it as your own classifier.

However, note that a projection is a well defined operation mathematically and it may be better to use it that way to avoid misunderstanding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29

Comment: You are right, I get my terminology together for next time. And use the pipeline. Thanks for help.

Comment: Forget what I said about the projection - both 2 and 3 are projections, just represented in different ways.

Comment: super awesome explanatory answer

Comment: Just wanted to say that `assert_array_almost_equal(VT[:30], pca.components_)` is not always true. In the implementation of PCA the signs are shuffled around between U and V. To mimic this shuffling replace `U, S, VT = np.linalg.svd(Xtrain - Xtrain.mean(0))` by `U, S, VT = np.linalg.svd(Xtrain - Xtrain.mean(0), full_matrices=False)` and insert `from sklearn.utils.extmath import svd_flip` followed by `U, VT = svd_flip(U, VT)`.

Comment: Does `X_train` in `loss = ((X_train - X_projected) ** 2).mean()` replace `Xtrain` variable defined earlier in the code?

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. Feel free to edit (probably Xtrain -> X_train would be best)

Comment: Thanks eickenberg. Great explanation as well, helped me out massively!

Comment: Model answer in every sense

Comment: I think the last part of the answer is wrong: The squared loss should be not `((data_projected - data_candidate) ** 2).mean()`. Instead, one should first calculate the distance per data point, then take the square of each distance, take the sum of those and divide by the number of data point. This can be done, e.g., via `np.sum((data_projected - data_candidate) ** 2, axis=1).mean()`. The answer here is - in effect - additionally dividing by the dimension of the data as well.

Comment: How to get the inverse transform when whitening=True? I expect there must be some multiplicaton with the eigenvalues or so?

Answer (score 6):

Adding on @eickenberg's post, here is how to do the pca reconstruction of digits' images:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn import decomposition

n_components = 10
image_shape = (8, 8)

digits = load_digits()
digits = digits.data

n_samples, n_features = digits.shape
estimator = decomposition.PCA(n_components=n_components, svd_solver='randomized', whiten=True)
digits_recons = estimator.inverse_transform(estimator.fit_transform(digits))

# show 5 randomly chosen digits and their PCA reconstructions with 10 dominant eigenvectors
indices = np.random.choice(n_samples, 5, replace=False)
plt.figure(figsize=(5,2))
for i in range(len(indices)):
    plt.subplot(1,5,i+1), plt.imshow(np.reshape(digits[indices[i],:], image_shape)), plt.axis('off')
plt.suptitle('Original', size=25)
plt.show()
plt.figure(figsize=(5,2))
for i in range(len(indices)):
    plt.subplot(1,5,i+1), plt.imshow(np.reshape(digits_recons[indices[i],:], image_shape)), plt.axis('off')
plt.suptitle('PCA reconstructed'.format(n_components), size=25)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]